# ts-migrate not adding function return types on conversion

Tags: javascript, typescript, ts-migrate

**ts-migrate** works pretty well with object and class properties but it is somehow not working with functions. I do not see any function return types added.

For example, my .js file was:

```
function mult(x, y) {
    return x - y;
}
```

The conversion result is:

```
function mult(x: any, y: any) {
    return x - y;
}
```

But it should have been:

```
function mult(x: number, y: number): number {
    return x - y;
}
```

Comment: You last example isn't a void function. It returns a value.

Comment: oops, I will correct that.

Comment: I don't really see a question here.